# Run Google Native Client (nacl_sdk) on Samsung Chromebook

Tags: linux, google-nativeclient, chromebook

I was trying to follow the the installation tutorial of the Native Client SDK found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/download#installing-the-stable-bundle). However, my Samsung Chromebook (in developer mode) does not want to run ./naclsdk (chmod +x done), but instead returns the following:

> 32-bit runtime environment was not found on this
>   system.  Specifically the 32-bit dynamic loader which is needed by the NaCl
>   compilers was not found ('/lib/ld-linux.so.2').  On modern debian/ubuntu
>   systems this is included in the 'libc6:i386' package.

On [here](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/introduction-to-portable-native-client) they write that the PNaCl should run on ARM computers, however, on some other forums I read that wasn't the case. I've tried enabling two flags, as described on a site which I can't post due to a lack of reputation, but it looks like that'll only change things when using PNaCl, not during the installation of the SDK.

Is it possible to install that SDK on my Chromebook and, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion: when the documentation says "PNaCl and NaCl work on ARM", it means the part that runs inside of Chrome which users would use. The SDK is currently only built for x86-64 Windows/Linux/OSX, and not for ARM. The main reason is that it's never been requested, probably because ARM machines are quite slow compared to usual development machines.

That being said, I don't think it's silly to use ARM as a development machine, and I've built my own PNaCl toolchain for ARM in the past. There are [build instructions](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/developing-pnacl) for the toolchain. I haven't built it recently, and it may have bitrotted a bit so if you run into issues I suggest [emailing the team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/native-client-discuss) or better yet sending a patch! I expect any issue to be fairly minor, especially if you only want to use `pnacl-clang` or `nacl-clang` (as opposed to the GCC toolchain).